# Is there a way to change Android Device Manager install location?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2022, android-device-manager

I have two drives on my computer, but I don't  have space on my default drive (C), so I now use my D drive. Yet, when I install a `Wear OS Large - API 33` on the Android Device Manager to run my Xamarin app, it says that there is not enough storage on the drive. I assume this is because it is trying to install on the C drive, not the D drive. Is there a working way to change the directory that new devices are installed on?

VS Version: Visual Studio 2022

I've tried setting the ENV variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` (not at the same time) to a folder I made in my new documents folder: `D:\<REDACTED>\Documents\Android Device Manager Devices`, but it still didn't do anything, even after restarting both Visual Studio and my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the default installation location of the Android emulator. The default installation location is on the C drive. You can change the `disk.dataPartition.size` and install it again. You can also check out this article to [manage your emulator devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?source=recommendations&tabs=windows&pivots=windows).

Comment: What will changing `disk.dataPartition.size` do? How would I modify it?

Comment: It will change the emulator disk size.  You said that you do not have the enough space to install the emulator. So, you can set the disk a small size for the emulator. Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?source=recommendations&tabs=windows&pivots=windows#new-device) you can refer to.

Comment: But my C disk quite literally has 0MB storage left. is there any way to change the install location?

Comment: You can see the `disk.dataPartition.size` option in the emulator property. If you still do not have the enough space for install the emulator. It is recommended that you can build more space for the disk C.

Comment: For now, there is no way to change the default installation location.

Comment: Is there a alternative? I am willing to go to extra steps if needed.

Comment: You can also use the Android physical device. If you have an Android phone, you can test the project on it.

Comment: How can I set this up on my Wear OS device?

Comment: You can check the Android document to set the physical device.